# DPDK ixgbe driver not rendering proper link status

Tags: dpdk

I called rte_eth_dev_stop() on my Ethernet Controller 10G X550T card , after this when I make a call to rte_eth_get_link_nowait() on same device , the link read from link register of the device still shows as UP!

But when I bring the device link down by bringing the other end of the connection physically down, the rte_eth_get_link_nowait() call shows the link as DOWN!

The server is running on a bare metal architecture.
The DPDK PMD is ixgbe.
DPDK version 18.05

why is this so ? any idea?

Comment: when raising dpdk question, please include the DPDK version used also. Along with the gcc version.

Comment: DPDK verison is 18.05

Comment: does this answer your query? please try using link_down API and check for link status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DPDK API `rte_eth_dev_set_link_down` is responsible for Link state down. While DPDK API `rte_eth_dev_stop` is responsible for internally stopping rx-tx queues and thereby making `rte_eth_rx_burst` and rte_eth_tx_burst` as 0 always.

Hence the expectation rte_eth_dev_stop to bring link state down for X550 is not true with DPDK PMD ixgbe.

Note:

1. unlike Linux `ifconfig up and ifconfig down`, the user space PMD dev_configure, start and stop are different. Please feel free to check the details in code.
2. with DPDK 20.11 return value is updated from `void` to `int` https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/rel_notes/release_20_11.html?highlight=rte_eth_dev_stop
3. Since `link state is governed by HW registers in the ASIC, different PMD may work differently`. Hence please check the code for other PMD for more details.

Comment: The ixgbe_dev_stop() has the following code:    if (hw->mac.ops.get_media_type(hw) == ixgbe_media_type_copper) {
2808                 /* Turn off the copper */
2809                 ixgbe_set_phy_power(hw, false);
2810         } else {
2811                 /* Turn off the laser */
2812                 ixgbe_disable_tx_laser(hw);
2813         } ,  this is what even ixgbe_dev_set_link_down() does. Hence it has to update the link status right ?

Comment: Have you tried `ixgbe_dev_set_link_down` and check if the link is really going down ?

Comment: No but it is the same piece of code , line by line. Does it make any difference?

Comment: yes, because DPDK PMD holds the link status as variable and not related to HW, where the register write with `ixgbe_set_phy_power` and `ixgbe_disable_tx_laser` are voluntary functions in which request are sent but there are no return check in PMD code to ensure if the it is done or not.

Comment: I got it , for Ethernet Controller 10G X550T card both function pointer for copper medium and laser medium is set to NULL , hence nothing happens.

Comment: correct, hence if you want DPDK library (ethdev) to update link state up/down rely on the `rte_eth_dev_set_link_down/up` to update in DPDK API. Based on vendor registers and firmware actual up/down varies with DPDK versions. Try using 20.11 (upcoming release) and check if it works.